# linkedin api getting user profile, work details without being logged in

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I would like to access user profile work history, current job without the user being logged in. Assuming the user has given permission previously.

I have got the access_token and access_secret, but how do I incorporate them into a url to produce a xml or json result?

http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=abcdefg

I am sorry for being vague, but the LinkedIn documentation is poor compared to facebook.

Facebook use

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_NAME?fields=work&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Is there something similar for LinkedIn?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I highly encourage you to use a library, instead of creating raw calls to the API, it will simplify your life:

There is a library for the most popular programming languages: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools .

Comment: I would still like to see how its done, then after I'm sure it does what I need I would use a library for that. if you know how this can be achieved with a library, please include link to direct documentation about this problem. I believe people are smart enough to find the link you provided on their own